# MVC 4 solution structure Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, directory-structure, renderpartial, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Well since most of the tutorials and demos chooses to put the partial view in shared folder im asking for a better way to do this.

My problem:
I want to use partial views in order to create a dynamic interface with reusable views. As i can with usercontrols. Since there might be a lot of partial views i want to put them in a seperate folder than the shared folder.

example:
How it looks today:

[View]

- [View.Home]

  - index.cshtml
- [View.Shared]

  - _layout.cshtml

A better way
[View]

- [View.Home]

  - index.cshtml
- [View.Shared]

  - _layout.cshtml
- [View.Shared.Partial]

  - partial1.cshtml
  - etc

Or should i rethink my approach enirely? if so how? if not what should i think about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of something I do,

- Application Wide used partial views - I put them in my Shared directory.
- Partial Views for a specific Controller - I put them in the Views/[ControllerName] Directory.

Comment: Ah yes, ofcourse. just in the starting pit of embracing mvc. so thank you Yasser for your help :) . Although if im building a larger scale project there might be a structural issue to put all Widely used partial views in the shared folder without a sub folder?